# how can i compare two lists and take only differences in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, compare

```
class BookmarkProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Animal> _bookmarks = [];

  Future<void> loadBookmark({
    String userNo,
  }) async {
    var url = '${myUrl}_API/bookmark.php';
    var response = await ioClient.post(
      url,
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "secreat"},
      body: jsonEncode(
        <String, dynamic>{
          'user_No': userNo,
        },
      ),
    );
    _bookmarks = [
      ...jsonDecode(response.body)
          .map<Animal>((json) => Animal.fromJSON(json))
          .toList()
    ]; // want to make change here.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

i want to optimize this code like save only differences between oldData and newData that i fetch with myAPI in _bookmarks. i mean in existing array _bookmarks.
i can not figure it out how.

Comment: check `Set` class official documentation

Answer (score 1):

Use **Sets** to do it. With sets you can easily achieve your goal and then convert is back into a list.

Here's a link to get you started - https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-sets

Comment: i got it. but a another problem is when new list has less items than oldList. Is it works same way both like delete and add?

Comment: or should i just use list.clear(), list.addAll()?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.